# How do I stop automation if 50% test methods are failed in testng?

Tags: java, testing, testng

I want to stop my execution if written @Test methods get failed more than 50%.

E.g:

```
public void LoginTest(){

    @Test
    public void ValidUserName(){

    }

    @Test
    public void InValidUserName(){
    }

    @Test
    public void ValidUserID(){
    }

    @Test
    public void ValidUserIDInvalidPassword(){
    }

    @Test
    public void EmptyUserNamePassword(){
    }
}
```

If `ValidUserName()`,`InValidUserName()` and `ValidUserID()` get failed that means LoginTest 50% @Test methods got failed and Now, I do not want to execute `ValidUserIDInvalidPassword()` and `EmptyUserNamePassword()`

It would be great if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: It would be good to understand why you have this requirement. Are your tests prohibitively slow?

Comment: No, Requirement is like I do not have to run if defined % @test methods get failed to avoid unnecessary execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `IInvokedMethodListener` interface and throw a `SkipException` when the threshold is reached. In the below code have used 30%.

```
public class MyMethodInvoke implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    private int failure = 0;

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        int testCount = testResult.getTestContext().getAllTestMethods().length; 
        if((failure * 1.0) / testCount > 0.3)
            throw new SkipException("Crossed the failure rate");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {        
        if(testResult.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)
            failure++;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Listeners({package.MyMethodInvoke.class})
public class Test {
```

It works for tests in a single class, no idea how it behaves with tests in multiple classes in a suite. Or even for a parallel execution.

Answer (score 1):

What you want makes no sense.
Try restructuring your methods with dependencies. Example from testNG page:

```
@Test
public void serverStartedOk() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" })
public void method1() {}
```

see: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods

**UPDATE:**

There is the concept of `successPercentage` but it is usually used per method and with combination with `invocationCount`. For example, in async invocations where the one cannot guarantee 100% invocations are successful. So, one can do:

```
//method is invocated 2 times. If 1 passes, test is considered OK/green.
@Test(timeOut = 2000, invocationCount = 2, successPercentage = 50)
public void waitForAnswer() throws InterruptedException{
...}
```

but this is not compatible with what you want.

**UPDATE 2:**
"What you want makes no sense." --> Read: "is not supported out of the box by TestNG". But there are some workarounds. See the nice answers in http://testng.1065351.n5.nabble.com/how-to-stop-a-test-suite-if-one-method-fails-td13441.html

Comment: Hi JonyD, I tried this logic and this will work if when you want to execute same test method multiple time and in that you want to check successPercentage rate. But I need to execute 1 Test Method one time only and calculate % on overall test methods

Comment: @Neerajkumar now I see what you meant. Very nice. TIL :). Grasshopper's answer is the best.